# How to plot ROC curve for the following set?

Tags: java, matlab, roc

I have a two sets

```
set1=[0.333; 0.509; 0.607; 1.172; 0.275; 0.762; 0.850; 0.920; 0.556; -0.046];
set2=[ 0.295; -0.203; -0.097; 0.633; 0.147; 0.356; 0.235; -0.054; -0.024; 0.377; -0.180; 0.512; 0.428; -0.129; 0.094];
```

How to plot ROC curve for it using any random threshold?

Comment: Looks like you haven't done the most basic research on what's a ROC curve... Start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic for instance.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: you can't.

Long answer:

1. ROC curve shows how a binary classifier performs as the decision threshold changes. This requires a "ground truth" that you don't have.
2. If you define a random threshold, you don't have a curve, only a point in the ROC space. The point of a ROC curve is to go over all possible points.

Comment: I think "grand truth" should be "ground truth".